# Python dataframe combining rows where first two column values inverse

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python and would very much appreciate your help! I have a dataframe with three columns and would like to combine the rows where the first two columns have the same associations (i.e. being in column A vs column B doesn't really matter in this situation) and sum their values in the third column. For example, starting with this dataframe:

```
A    B    C

x    y    5

z    z    6

y    x    4

z    y    3

y    z    2
```

I would like to be able to produce a dataframe like this (combining `x y` with `y x`; and `z y` with `y z`):

```
A    B    C

x    y    9

z    z    6

y    z    5
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Here's my code so far:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k:dict(v) for k,v in dic.items()}).fillna(0)
MG_df = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns
{'level_0':'Source','level_1':'Target', 0:'Weight'})
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(MG_df[['Source','Target']].values, axis=1))
MG_df.groupby(['Source','Target']).Weight.sum().reset_index()
MG_df = MG_df[MG_df.Weight != 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort columns A and B and then use groupby

```
df[['A','B']] = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['A','B']].values, axis=1))
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).C.sum().reset_index()


    A   B   C
0   x   y   9
1   y   z   5
2   z   z   6
```

Comment: `np.sort(df[['A','B']].values` - very nice idea!

Comment: @MaxU, Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks so much! I still seem to be getting the redundant values (i.e. x y and y x are both listed with individual values for the 3rd column). My code is below. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not assigning the result of sort back to the dataframe. Try MG_df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(MG_df[['Source','Target']].values, axis=1)) and then MG_df = MG_df.groupby(['Source','Target']).Weight.sum().reset_index()

Comment: Let me know if the issue is resolved with my earlier comment

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this! I get a KeyError for 'Source' when I do this. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Key error Source means that your column name is not Source. Print df.columns to see the exact column name and try again. Sometimes they have spaces within like ' Source'